# Postgres: UPDATE and return result of SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

My table may look like this:

| created | last_read | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-15 15:51:50 | *NULL* | *BINARY* |
| 2021-10-14 12:22:13 | *NULL* | *BINARY* |
| 2021-10-13 06:32:44 | 2021-10-14 16:44:08 | *BINARY* |
| 2021-10-12 16:05:07 | 2021-10-13 17:21:09 | *BINARY* |

**What I want to do:** SELECT x rows ordered by created ASC and `last_read` ASC and set time `last_read` of the selected rows to `NOW()`.

The SELECT would look like this:

```sql
SELECT data
FROM my_table
ORDER BY last_read NULLS FIRST, created
LIMIT 3
```

I would then take the result set and apply the following UPDATE statement:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET last_read = NOW()
```

**Question:** How would a query look like that does both of the above **and** returns the result of the SELECT?

If the returned data is before or prior to the UPDATE doesn’t matter, since I only select the data column.

I’ve tried

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET last_read = NOW()
RETURNING data
```

However, I cannot provide ORDER BY and LIMIT to this. Therefore, it doesn't produce the desired result, but updates and returns all rows.

I may also think of using a subquery to update rows based on the SELECT. But then those rows wouldn’t be returned as a result.

Comment: How do know in advance that `LIMIT 3` will get all the rows where last_read is null' , And why would you want to update the date on the third row? Yes it was selected but only as side effect of the limit and number of null values.

Comment: I don’t want to just fetch the rows where last_read is null, but all of them (up to limit). last_read = null should only be prioritized when ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM mytable
  ORDER BY last_read NULLS FIRST, created
  LIMIT 3
)
UPDATE mytable t
SET last_read = NOW()
FROM cte
WHERE cte.created = t.created
RETURNING t.data;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3723e33f9e58399c581b9703972c4fcd)